# Java get size of event.getDragboard().getFiles().stream().map(File::length).toString());

Tags: java

I woudlike to get size of my file :

```
event.getDragboard().getFiles().stream().map(File::getName).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")),               
event.getDragboard().getFiles().stream().map(File::getPath).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")),
event.getDragboard().getFiles().stream().map(File::length).toString());
```

The problem actually I get correct Name and path but not size:

```
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@5b41d7e4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling:

```java
event.getDragboard().getFiles().stream().map(File::length).toString());
```

you are converting `Stream<Long>` into `String`.

What you want actually is to convert every `Long` in the stream into `String` and then join them as you did with path or name.

**How to convert `Stream<Long>` into `String`?**

```
getFiles().stream()
          .map(File::length) // Stream<Long>
          .map(String::valueOf) // Stream<String>
          .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")); // String
```

The function `String.valueOf()` takes a `Long` and returns it's `String` representation, so we can use this function for conversion from `Long` to `String`.

**How to convert `Stream<Long>` into `Long`?**

In case you would like to get `sum` [1] of all `Long`s in the stream, you can use `sum` function of `LongStream`.

```
getFiles().stream()
          .map(File::length)  // Stream<Long>
          .mapToLong(Long::longValue) // LongStream
          .sum(); // Long
```

By calling `mapToLong` we have converted `Stream<Long>` into `LongStream`.

---

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#sum()